# How to tell a function in DLL whether in _stdcall convention or in _cdecl convention?

Tags: dll

I have a dll and can see the function names with dependency walker, then how can I tell the function was in `_stdcall` convention or `in _cdecl` convention?

I ask this question because I noticed that there're lots of discussions on when to use `_stdcall` and when to use `_cdecl` convention to export functions in DLL.

It's OK when the source code of DLL is available, but how about when only a DLL file is available?

Comment: What language are you using?  C++?  You should tag the question with the right language to help get more eyes on it.

Comment: The documentation for the DLL should tell you. The information is not included in the DLL.

Comment: The real situation is that I want to load the DLL with Python or Java. The DLL is built with VC++ and a .def file.

Comment: If you have the source code you can just read it and see what the expected calling convention is. If you don't have source code, you will have to consult the documentation. The information is not recorded in the DLL or the DEF file.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has all of the VC++ [naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58.aspx) well documented. Start there.

It's possible to override the export naming, so it might not be a perfect way for you to distinguish things. You can also disassemble the functions and pay close attention to how it is using registers and stack to figure it out pretty quickly.